# SQL Query Pulling NULL value when JOINED with other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello and thanks for reading.  I seem to be having an issue pulling a date from a field from my Query. All other fields in the Query pull correctly and it doesn't throw an error.  However, all Document.ServiceDTTM columns show NULL. There are no NULL values in the Document table so I am not sure why this is displaying. Am I using an incorrect JOIN type somewhere?

```
    DECLARE @StartDate datetime
    DECLARE @EndDate datetime

    SET @StartDate = '2015-08-01'
    SET @EndDate = '2015-09-01'
    USE Works

    SELECT Patient_Iorg.organizationMRN AS MRN, IDX_User.AUsername AS TWUser, Document.ServiceDTTM, DocumentEvent.eventDTTM, Document_Type_de.EntryName AS NoteName FROM Document (nolock)
        JOIN DocumentEvent ON Document.documentid = DocumentEvent.documentid
        JOIN Document_Type_de ON Document.documenttypede = Document_Type_de.ID
        JOIN IDX_User ON DocumentEvent.userid = IDX_User.ID
        JOIN Person ON Document.PatientID = Person.ID
        LEFT JOIN Patient_Iorg ON Person.id = Patient_Iorg.PersonID and Patient_Iorg.InternalOrganization = 3
    WHERE 
        DocumentEvent.documenteventde IN (18)
    AND
        DocumentEvent.eventDTTM >= @StartDate 
    AND 
        DocumentEvent.eventDTTM <= @EndDate 
    AND 
        Document.Status LIKE 'Final%' 
    AND 
        Document.DocumentTypeDE IN (158) 

ORDER BY 
    eventDTTM
```

IT OUTPUTS THE FOLLOWING:

```
XXXXXX  adoctor     NULL    8/1/2015    Note
XXXXXX  adoctor     NULL    8/1/2015    Note
XXXXXX  aprovider       NULL    8/1/2015    Note
XXXXXX  aprovider       NULL    8/1/2015    Note
XXXXXX  aprovider       NULL    8/1/2015    Note
XXXXXX  aprovider       NULL    8/1/2015    Note
XXXXXX  aprovider       NULL    8/1/2015    Note
XXXXXX  aprovider       NULL    8/1/2015    Note
XXXXXX  aprovider       NULL    8/1/2015    Note
```

Comment: I trust the results of the query:  there are `NULL` values in `Document.ServiceDTTM`.  You might try setting up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: There are zero NULL values in Document.ServiceDTTM. If I run a SELECT query on the Document table (say SELECT * FROM Document) the entire ServiceDTTM column has date values for every single record

Comment: I don't have a specific fix for you, but would suggest you change "Document.ServiceDTTM" to "CASE WHEN Document.ServiceDTTM is null THEN 'It is Null' ELSE Document.ServiceDTTM END"

Comment: @gmrstudios, you'd better run `SELECT * FROM Document WHERE ServiceDTTM IS NULL` to verify that there are no `NULL` values there.